# Thunderbird saves new draft instead of saving over it

Tags: email, thunderbird

This seems to be an intended feature of Mozilla thunderbird (running latest version).  The problem is, if you have auto save enabled to every minute, you can potentially have hundreds of drafts cluttering your remote folder that you would have to sweep out at the end of the week.  It's an unnecessary inconvenience that a user should not have to go through should Mozilla designed their software right (or added an option to specify the save behavior on the remote folder)

I don't want to use local folders for drafts because then I edit drafts from multiple devices, which is an absolute must for me since I do that in order to schedule send emails.  Is there anything that can be done about this problem without switching mail clients?

Comment: How have you defined the auto-save ?

Comment: I don't use auto save.  The problem is when any draft message is saved, the revision gets saved as a new copy, instead of being overwritten.  This behavior has been described here and doesn't appear to have any kind of solution other than to use local folders to save drafts which inhibits me from opening drafts from other devices.

https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a3536/thunderbird-saving-multiple-drafts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird itself offers no solution, but an add-on can at least
help with the cleanup work :
[Remove Duplicate Messages](https://addons.thunderbird.net/En-us/thunderbird/addon/removedupes/?src=ss):

> This add-on lets you search messages in one or several folders to
> locate duplicates: Messages which are identical - according to some
> comparison criteria you chose.
>
> Features:
>
> - Wide choice of comparison criteria (subject, author, send time, CC list, flags, etc).
> - Review dialog for double-checking which duplicates to delete and which to keep.
> - Relatively fast; should easily be able to handle 100K emails and more
> - Supports comparison of message bodies as a comparison criteria (but this slows thing down of course).
> - Good performance on local folders with large number of messages; reasonable performance with IMAP and RSS accounts.
> - Spiffy toolbar button+menu for quick access.
> - Free (GPL/LGPL/MPL license)

For the very last version of the add-on, you may go to its
[Github page](https://github.com/eyalroz/removedupes/).

To access the settings of this add-on, go to menu
*Tools > Add-ons and themes > Remove Duplicate Messages*.

Comment: For me the duplicate messages don't appear in thunderbird, only the remote server.  So this add on just returns that there are no duplicate messages and also, it has to be done manually and can't be automated.  Another negative.  I guess when the time is right I will just switch to using google workspace email and use their official client since it is much better than thunderbird + office 365.